# Pointer to the string data type

Tags: c++, winapi

Having simple code like below:

```
using namespace std;
...
string str = "Abc";
string* str_ptr = &str;
str_ptr[0] = 'D';

sprintf_s(MsgBuff, 300, "%s", str_ptr);
OutputDebugStringA(MsgBuff);
```

The output is just `D`, not as i expected `Dbc`?

Doing the similar things with C style strings:

```
char str[] = "Abc";
char* str_ptr = str;
str_ptr[0] = 'D';
```

Indead returns `Dbc`.

Comment: How does this ever work? The compiler should error saying that you can't convert `string` to `string*`.

Comment: Is that a `std::string` or something else?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes, that's standard C++ string data type from std.

Comment: @Aplet123, Sorry, my mistake, now corrected.

Comment: `str_ptr[0]` is a `std::string&`, not a `char&`

Comment: You should be able to find the answers to these kinds of questions in any [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116).

Comment: Hi,if any answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`%s` in `sprintf`s format string expects a C-style string and nothing else.  Your code should therefore be something like:

```
string str = "Abc";
char *char_ptr = str.data ();
char_ptr[0] = 'D';
sprintf_s(MsgBuff, 300, "%s", char_ptr);
OutputDebugStringA(MsgBuff);
```

Comment: OK, that works, but what when i'd like to use string data type pointer (`string* str_ptr = &str`)?

Comment: Well, you can't.  You could, however, do `str [0] = 'D';`

Comment: So doing `string* str_ptr = &str` we just creating a pointer to the "string" class an is completly different what the C style poiner (`char str[] = "Abc";
char* str_ptr = str;`) to char is?

Comment: @Derek81:  The first is a pointer to `std::string`. the second one you would expect to be a pointer to `char[]`, but due to quirks in C, the `char[]` sometimes pretends to be a `char*`, so `str_ptr` ends up a pointer to the _characters_, instead of a pointer to a C-String like you'd expect.  It's not `std::string`, behaving weird, it's `char[]` that behaves weird.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, pointers of string type are not the same as pointers of char type. You can refer to the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    string* s = new string("Abc");
    cout << s << endl;
    cout << *s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

And `*s` is the same as `str[0]`, so the `str_ptr[0] ='D'` you write will overwrite the original string.

Also, when you use `str_ptr` directly, you are using its address instead of its elements, which is different from using:

```
char* str_ptr = str;
str_ptr[0] = 'D';
```

The string is different from the char type string in the C language. The string pointer points to a class object. If you want to modify the content of the string through the string pointer, you can try the following code:

```
string* str_ptr = &str;
str_ptr->at(0) = 'D';
```

And you cannot directly use `str_ptr` as the parameter of `%s`, it should be `str_ptr->c_str()`.

Here is the complete sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    string str = "Abc";
    string* str_ptr = &str;
    str_ptr->at(0) = 'D';

    char MsgBuff[300];
    sprintf_s(MsgBuff, 300, "\nMSG = %s\n", str_ptr->c_str());
    OutputDebugStringA(MsgBuff);

    return 0;
}
```

And it works for me:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
string str = "Abc";
string* str_ptr = &str;
str_ptr[0] = 'D';
```

is the same as

```cpp
string str = "Abc";
string* str_ptr = &str;
*str_ptr = 'D';
```

is the same as

```cpp
string str = "Abc";
str = 'D';
```

`std::string` has an overloaded `operator=` for assigning a `char` value, which is why the string becomes `"D"` and not `"Dbc"`.

However, `sprintf_s(MsgBuff, 300, "%s", str_ptr);` is *undefined behavior*, as `%s` expects a `char*` pointer to a null-terminated C string, which `str_ptr` is not.

So, the *only* possible way that `str_ptr` could produce a viable null-terminated C string when *misinterpreted* as a `char*` in this example is if your compiler's `std::string` class implements Short String Optimization, and its SSO buffer is the 1st data member in the class. Both of which are *implementation details* that you can't rely on when writing standards-compliant code.